# Merging two dockerfiles in one

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, conda

I have a custom docker image that i work upon.
The dockerfile i created starts with

```
FROM ubuntu
```

Now, i want to add cadquery to my packages.
Hopefully, there is a dockerfile for doing that.
Here it is:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
RUN apt install -y libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN conda install conda-build
RUN apt-get install -y git
WORKDIR /
RUN git clone https://github.com/cadquery/cadquery.git
WORKDIR /cadquery
RUN conda env create -n cq -f environment.yml
RUN echo "source activate cq" > ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/cq/bin:$PATH
WORKDIR /testing
```

(source: https://github.com/RubenRubens/cq-testing/blob/master/Dockerfile)

However, as you can see, it uses a different `FROM` command than mine.
What i want to do, is keep my dockerfile, and just add conda, and cadquery somehow.

I researched a bit into the `continuumio/miniconda3` image, but i am to sure what is the best startegy to use after all.

I know that you can have two different `FROM` commands in your dockerfile, but is this recommended?

If yes, how the structure of the dockerfile should be?

IF no, meaning it is NOT recommended to use two different `FROM` commands, how should i structure my dockerfile?

Should i use the `FROM` ubuntu dockerfile, and just add conda manually, and then proceed like this dockerfile i pasted here?

EDIT: I forgot to say that one important thing to note, is that miniconda is installed from a `.sh` file that you download
(source: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html)

So i am not sure if using two `FROM` commands (and how), or just having the basic ubuntu image and downloading that `.sh` would work best.

Comment: This is something that you surely can do if you need it, see the documentation of [multistage-build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

Comment: There is no way to merge two different images.  Having two separate `FROM` lines will create two separate images and in effect only the last one is used.  If that Miniconda image is based on Ubuntu (or Debian) you should be able to `RUN` the same commands, though.